# How to select columns that are similar values and calculate quantity and sum of prices

Tags: sql, sum

Hey I have a table in my Database like this that you see below.
I want to select "DocumentNumber" where they have similar values.
You see that there is three 10006513 values

```
  Ducumentnumber    requestType    price    quantity       sum of price  

      10006513                       1500
      10006513                       2500
      10006513                       7500
```

I want to select them and write e.g: quantity = 3 and I calculate sum of price of them.
I want a good query in sql server 2008

Comment: Since you don't know how to do something very fundamental, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Ducumentnumber,Count(quantity) as Quatity,sum(price)
from table1
group by Ducumentnumber
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49390/1)**

Comment: Did you know that COUNT(1) adds no value at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649

Comment: I wrote this and I cant bring request type in my query

select  distinct documentnumber , sum(price)as totalPrice from sheet
group by DocumentNumber
order by DocumentNumber